# How to use sqlite database to store fetch data and retrieve

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I build a tv app with online server/admin panel.I want to save fetched data to app memory from server.It means,if internet is not available, the app shows old fetched data retrieved from sqlite database.Please help me to do it?.I have created Offline database file, but I do not know how to do it.I am posting the codes of Activity, Fragment and Offline database. Please help me to configure my problem.
a Bundle of thanks in advance...!!!

```js
public class ActivityDetailCategory extends AppCompatActivity {


    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private AdapterChannel adapterChannel;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private Call<CallbackDetailCategory> callbackCall = null;
    private int post_total = 0;
    private int failed_page = 0;
    private Category category;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    int counter = 1;
    private AdView adView;
    View view;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category_details);
        view = findViewById(android.R.id.content);



        if (Config.ENABLE_RTL_MODE) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

            }
        } else {
            Log.d("Log", "Working in Normal Mode, RTL Mode is Disabled");
        }

        loadBannerAd();
        loadInterstitialAd();

        category = (Category) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(Constant.EXTRA_OBJC);


        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue, R.color.red);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //set data and list adapter
        adapterChannel = new AdapterChannel(this, recyclerView, new ArrayList<Channel>());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterChannel);


        // on item list clicked
        adapterChannel.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterChannel.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, Channel obj, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityDetailChannel.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_CATEGORY, obj.category_name);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_ID, obj.channel_id);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_NAME, obj.channel_name);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_IMAGE, obj.channel_image);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_URL, obj.channel_url);
                intent.putExtra(Constant.KEY_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION, obj.channel_description);
                startActivity(intent);


                showInterstitialAd();
            }
        });

        // detect when scroll reach bottom
        adapterChannel.setOnLoadMoreListener(new AdapterChannel.OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                if (post_total > adapterChannel.getItemCount() && current_page != 0) {
                    int next_page = current_page + 1;
                    requestAction(next_page);
                } else {
                    adapterChannel.setLoaded();
                }
            }
        });

        // on swipe list
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (callbackCall != null && callbackCall.isExecuted()) {
                    callbackCall.cancel();
                }
                adapterChannel.resetListData();
                requestAction(1);
            }
        });

        requestAction(1);

        setupToolbar();

    }

    public void setupToolbar() {
        final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(category.category_name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

            case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;

            case R.id.search:
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivitySearch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
    }

    private void displayApiResult(final List<Channel> channels) {
        adapterChannel.insertData(channels);
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (channels.size() == 0) {
            showNoItemView(true);
        }
    }

    private void requestPostApi(final int page_no) {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = RestAdapter.createAPI();
        callbackCall = apiInterface.getCategoryDetailsByPage(category.cid, page_no, Config.LOAD_MORE);
        callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackDetailCategory>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CallbackDetailCategory> call, Response<CallbackDetailCategory> response) {
                CallbackDetailCategory resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.status.equals("ok")) {
                    post_total = resp.count_total;
                    displayApiResult(resp.posts);
                } else {
                    onFailRequest(page_no);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CallbackDetailCategory> call, Throwable t) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) onFailRequest(page_no);
            }

        });
    }

    private void onFailRequest(int page_no) {
        failed_page = page_no;
        adapterChannel.setLoaded();
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (NetworkCheck.isConnect(getApplicationContext())) {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.failed_text));
        } else {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.no_internet_text));
        }
    }

    private void requestAction(final int page_no) {
        showFailedView(false, "");
        showNoItemView(false);
        if (page_no == 1) {
            swipeProgress(true);
        } else {
            adapterChannel.setLoading();
        }
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestPostApi(page_no);
            }
        }, Constant.DELAY_TIME);
    }

    private void showFailedView(boolean show, String message) {
        View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.lyt_failed);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.failed_message)).setText(message);
        if (show) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.failed_retry)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestAction(failed_page);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showNoItemView(boolean show) {
        View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.lyt_no_item);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_item_message)).setText(R.string.no_post_found);
        if (show) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void swipeProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (!show) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            return;
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (callbackCall != null && callbackCall.isExecuted()) {
            callbackCall.cancel();
        }
    }

    public void loadBannerAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_BANNER_ADS) {
            MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.admob_app_id));
            adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLeftApplication() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

        } else {
            Log.d("AdMob", "AdMob Banner is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void loadInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS) {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getApplicationContext());
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_unit_id));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("AdMob", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void showInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS) {

            if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                if (counter == Config.ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS_INTERVAL) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    counter = 1;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("AdMob", "Interstitial Ad is Disabled");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("AdMob", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }

}
```

```js
public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {

    private View root_view, parent_view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private AdapterCategory adapterCategory;
    public static final String EXTRA_OBJC = "key.EXTRA_OBJC";
    private Call<CallbackCategories> callbackCall = null;
    private StaggeredGridLayoutManager gaggeredGridLayoutManager;
    DatabaseHandlerFavorite databaseHandler;
    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    private Offlinedatabase databaseHelper;

    int counter = 1;



    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, null);
        parent_view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        databaseHelper          = new Offlinedatabase(getActivity());


        loadInterstitialAd();

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) root_view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout_category);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.orange, R.color.green, R.color.blue, R.color.red);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewCategory);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);



        gaggeredGridLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(1, 1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gaggeredGridLayoutManager);




        //set data and list adapter
        adapterCategory = new AdapterCategory(getActivity(), new ArrayList<Category>());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterCategory);

        // on item list clicked
        adapterCategory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterCategory.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View v, Category obj, int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityDetailCategory.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_OBJC, obj);
                startActivity(intent);

                showInterstitialAd();
            }
        });

        // on swipe list
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                adapterCategory.resetListData();
                requestAction();
            }
        });

        requestAction();

        return root_view;
    }

    private void displayApiResult(final List<Category> categories) {
        adapterCategory.setListData(categories);
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (categories.size() == 0) {
            showNoItemView(true);
        }
    }

    private void requestCategoriesApi() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = RestAdapter.createAPI();
        callbackCall = apiInterface.getAllCategories();
        callbackCall.enqueue(new Callback<CallbackCategories>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<CallbackCategories> call, Response<CallbackCategories> response) {
                CallbackCategories resp = response.body();
                if (resp != null && resp.status.equals("ok")) {
                    displayApiResult(resp.categories);
                } else {
                    onFailRequest();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<CallbackCategories> call, Throwable t) {
                if (!call.isCanceled()) onFailRequest();
            }

        });
    }

    private void onFailRequest() {
        swipeProgress(false);
        if (NetworkCheck.isConnect(getActivity())) {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.failed_text));
        } else {
            showFailedView(true, getString(R.string.no_internet_text));
        }
    }

    private void requestAction() {
        showFailedView(false, "");
        swipeProgress(true);
        showNoItemView(false);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                requestCategoriesApi();
            }
        }, Constant.DELAY_TIME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        swipeProgress(false);
        if(callbackCall != null && callbackCall.isExecuted()){
            callbackCall.cancel();
        }
    }

    private void showFailedView(boolean flag, String message) {
        View lyt_failed = (View) root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_failed_category);
        ((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.failed_message)).setText(message);
        if (flag) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_failed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        ((Button) root_view.findViewById(R.id.failed_retry)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                requestAction();
            }
        });
    }

    private void showNoItemView(boolean show) {
        View lyt_no_item = (View) root_view.findViewById(R.id.lyt_no_item_category);
        ((TextView) root_view.findViewById(R.id.no_item_message)).setText(R.string.no_category_found);
        if (show) {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lyt_no_item.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lyt_no_item.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void swipeProgress(final boolean show) {
        if (!show) {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            return;
        }
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(show);
            }
        });
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        Resources r = getResources();
        return Math.round(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics()));
    }

    private void loadInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS) {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(getActivity());
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_interstitial_unit_id));
            interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d("AdMob", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }

    private void showInterstitialAd() {
        if (Config.ENABLE_ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS) {

            if (interstitialAd != null && interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                if (counter == Config.ADMOB_INTERSTITIAL_ADS_INTERVAL) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                    counter = 1;
                } else {
                    counter++;
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("AdMob", "Interstitial Ad is Disabled");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("AdMob", "AdMob Interstitial is Disabled");
        }
    }}
```

```js
public class Offlinedatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "db_channel_favorite";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_channel_favorite";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

    private static final String KEY_CAT_NAME = "CAT_NAME";
    private static final String KEY_CHANNEL_ID = "channel_id";
    private static final String KEY_CHANNEL_NAME = "channel_name";
    private static final String KEY_CHANNEL_IMAGE = "channel_image";
    private static final String KEY_CHANNEL_URL = "channel_url";
    private static final String KEY_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "channel_description";

    public Offlinedatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //Create tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_CAT_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CHANNEL_ID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CHANNEL_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CHANNEL_IMAGE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CHANNEL_URL + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT"
                + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    //Insert values to the table contacts
    public void addtodatabase(Channel pj){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_CAT_NAME, pj.getCategory_name());
        values.put(KEY_CHANNEL_ID, pj.getChannel_id());
        values.put(KEY_CHANNEL_NAME, pj.getChannel_name());
        values.put(KEY_CHANNEL_IMAGE, pj.getChannel_image());
        values.put(KEY_CHANNEL_URL, pj.getChannel_url());
        values.put(KEY_CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION, pj.getChannel_description());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach is to use `Room` persistence library. Check the Google Code Labs:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-persistence/#0
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0

Answer (score 0):

Check this out if you are using Sqlite without room support 
[Sqlite Android](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)